# Handling COR dump issue with purify

Tags: c++, coredump, purify

I an instrumenting a C++application using IBM purify and I get the issue COR dump and my program aborts although when run from terminal it runs fine. Can anyone tell me what is this COR dump and how to handle with it?
Platform: `RHEL 64bit`

Thanx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the software you are using is licensed, please contact IBM.